# React dnd drag item different from actual item

Tags: react-dnd

I try to dnd items from a list to a bucket.
The items have `id, title, description`

**Problem:**
When dragging the item labelled `value: 1, title: foo , description: bar`, randomly another item from the list are selected instead.

```
Cards List
value: 1, title: foo , description: bar
value: a, title: aaa , description: AAA
value: x, title: xxx , description: XXX
value: y, title: yyy , description: YYY
```

```
const FunctionCard = props => {

  const { value, title, description} = props

  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
    type: "Card",
    item: () => { console.log('item X selected', value, title, description); return ({ id:value })},
    collect: (monitor) => { 
      console.log("collector drags item X", monitor.getItem()); 
      return ({
       isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
       handlerId: monitor.getHandlerId()
    })}
  }));
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to assign dependencies to the hooks `useDrag, useDrop` (see [github issue](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/3337))

```
const FunctionCard = props => {

  const { value, title, description} = props

  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
    type: "Card",
    item: () => { console.log('item X selected', value, title, description); return ({ id:value })},
    collect: (monitor) => { 
      console.log("collector drags item X", monitor.getItem()); 
      return ({
       isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
       handlerId: monitor.getHandlerId()
    })}
  }), [value, title, description]);
...
```

Comment: hey, thanks for this answer, the problem is when those three variables aren't changing, means that that dependency array is useless

Comment: The dependency array is specifically to only have the hook fired once that dependencies stated in the array change; At least the drag target changes, so this needs to be added. If that's an object then you might want to look into custom comparison function and lodash deep clone